# Can not fire change event while using jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue.The change event can not fire while input has some value using jQuery. I am explaining my code below.

```
<input name="" type="text"  class="inputfield" id="auto">
```

```js
var city = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'
];

$('#auto').autocomplete({
    source:[city],
    minLength: 1,
    change: function (event, ui) { alert('hello'); }
});
```

Here I need when one value will select from city array to input field the change event should fire which is not happening in my case. Please help me.

Comment: Try using 'select' rather than 'change'... select: function (event, ui) { alert('hello'); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add autoFocus and on focus fire the alert

```js
var city = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'
];

$('#auto').autocomplete({
    source: city,
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
focus: function(event, ui) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input name="" type="text" class="inputfield" id="auto">
```

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event is working fine, but note that it only fires when the element is blurred after a change is made to its value.

If you want the event to fire when a selection is made, use the `select` event:

```
$('#auto').autocomplete({
    source: city,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vesqhqb/)

Comment: Great !! a speedy and quick response.

Comment: still its not working in my code.Can you mention jquery autocomplete version.

Comment: It's using jQueryUI 1.92. You can check it in the fiddle. Also, check your code for errors